# What Is This Small Peak That Always Occurs Within Ketone Infra-Red Analysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, ir-spectroscopy

After looking at a bunch of IR spectrums for ketones, I have noticed this tiny peak that I circled on the diagram below. Does anyone know what it actually is and if I can always use it to distinguish a ketone vs aldehyde?

[image]

Comment: It's an overtone peak, double the frequency of the carbonyl. [Look at this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHFIzSi9t_k).

Comment: Not quite double it is from 1st to 3rd vibrational level. It would be nice to have the frequency.